# Channel Videos youtube video upload: "not supported since april 15 2015"

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

I have started to have a problem uploading my videos from youtube since April with Channel Videos. Every time I do I only get a youtube place holder video telling me that the app is no longer supported by youtube. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

DevDemon released Channel Videos 3.2 recently which addresses the YouTube API changes. See: https://twitter.com/devdemon/status/596450483788771329